# Centering Custom Action Bar Items

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-actionbar

I have a custom action bar that contains two items (the blue buttons) that I would like to be centered.  Currently, they are slightly left of center.  I want to ensure that the buttons are centered on all screen sizes.  What is the best way for me to accomplish this?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my XML **project_action_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@drawable/left_rounded_rect_selected"
            android:src="@drawable/list_white"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="0.0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@drawable/right_rounded_rect_deselected"
            android:src="@drawable/map_blue"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my Activity:

```
private void showActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);      
        ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);        

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.project_action_bar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(view, lp);

        View v = actionBar.getCustomView();
}
```

I also added the refresh and drop down menu here:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.refresh, Menu.NONE, "refresh")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);       

        SubMenu optionsMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Options Item");
        optionsMenu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.delete_project, Menu.NONE, "Delete Project")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
        optionsMenu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.logout, Menu.NONE, "Log Out")
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);        
        MenuItem optionsMenuItem = optionsMenu.getItem();

        optionsMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        optionsMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_overflow);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: give this a go   -- android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"  or actually that might not work --try - android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"  and try with -- android:layout_weight="1" for the buttons

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are centered within the custom view, but the custom view is not centered within the action bar.

The custom view fills the space between the home icon and the menu actions.  If the menu actions take up more room than the home icon (as it apparently does in your case), the custom view will not be centered in the action bar.

If you really want to achieve this, my suggestion would be to get the width of the screen and the width of the home icon, then do some math to figure out what the left margin should be in order to make the buttons appear centered.

You might be able to find the width of the home icon in a style attribute somewhere (because the width varies between different screen sizes).

I wouldn't want to figure that out.  I would just change the button color to match the menu action icons and right-justify them.  Or maybe do a custom menu action view/action provider instead of a custom title view.